# Is it possible to change the Font type and size in UITableView?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I want to change Font type and size in `UITableView`. For example, how would I set it to Tahoma?

Comment: your question is a touch generic. It would be useful to know what sort of effect you are trying to achieve. The below answer shows how to modify the font of a UITableViewCell. You are also free to define you own entirely new UIView subclass to display in the cell

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:144];
```

where `cell` is a `UITableViewCell` you would return in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

[Tahoma is not shipped with iOS by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700280/can-i-free-use-tahoma-font-in-iphone-app-development), nor can you legally copy it without a proper license. But you could provide a custom free font if you don't like Arial, see *[How to include and use new fonts in iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969329/how-to-include-and-use-new-fonts-in-iphone-sdk)*.

Comment: *** Assertion failure in -[UILabel setFont:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-963.10/UILabel.m:445

Comment: @RAGOpoR: Because Tahoma doesn't exist on the iPhoneOS.

Comment: how did i know which font are available for it?

Comment: @RAGOpoR: Check `[UIFont familyNames]`. The default ones can be found also in http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/UIFont.

Comment: Another handy list of iOS 4/5/6 fonts is: http://iosfonts.com  Also, Apple's font list for iOS 5 & 6: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4980 http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5484

Comment: Can I set this in app delegate for all tableviews?

Answer (score 7):

To add to [KennyTM's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224671/kennytm) answer:

You can use **`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`** delegate method of `UITableView` to configure your `UITableViewCell` like this:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
   cell.detailTextLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16.0];
   cell.detailTextLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

Apple document reads:

> *A table view sends this message to its delegate just before it uses cell to draw a row, thereby permitting the delegate to customize the
>   cell object before it is displayed. This method gives the delegate a
>   chance to override state-based properties set earlier by the table
>   view, such as selection and background color. After the delegate
>   returns, the table view sets only the alpha and frame properties, and
>   then only when animating rows as they slide in or out.*