# Trying to install custom font in xcode 4.2, iOS 5.0, but receiving error "Validation failed:

Tags: ios4, ios5, xcode4.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to include and use new fonts in iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969329/how-to-include-and-use-new-fonts-in-iphone-sdk)

I would like to add a custom font to my project, however I am having some problems.  I have a ttf file entitled "Herculanum Regular.ttf".  I added the file to my project, and added the following lines to my InfoPlist.strings file:

```
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
<string>Herculanum Regular.ttf</string>
</array>
```

However, I am continue to receive an error that reads:

Validation failed: The data couldn't be read because it has been corrupted.  Why is this not working?

Thanks for your help and take care.

Comment: try other font or otf fonts if you believe that's font problem

Comment: I'm sorry I did not know how that worked.  I accepted some answers officially on my other questions.

Comment: Also, GameBit, I tried another font, and I receive the same error.

Comment: Where did you get the font files?

Comment: I got the font files from some website online that has downloadable ttf files

Comment: Also, I tried an otf file, it doesn't work and it gives me the same error