# Tamil font in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uifont, custom-font, tamil

I try to install Tamil font name `Bamini.ttf` in `xcode 4.2` and I made the specific changes in `info.plist`.

Yet its not showing in Interface builder? Can any one help me to sort out this issue?

Comment: May be this one helps

[See the Answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454486/trying-to-install-custom-font-in-xcode-4-2-ios-5-0-but-receiving-error-valida/8464078#8464078

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know new font that you've installed will never be listed in Interface builder.However you can use it in your project like this:

1. Import `yourfont.ttf` into your project (check the "copy items into destination group's folder" and "add to targets").
2. Open appname-info.plist
   a. add a new row and name it `Fonts provided by application` (It's an array of strings)
   b. add an entry with the `Bamini.ttf`

   Then try the following code

   ```
   UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Font name" size:18];
   [txtLabel setFont:myFont];
   ```

*Font name can be different form file name. You can check font name by opening that font.
[image]

this will work for sure.