# Custom font is not working in my App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios5

In my iPhone app,

I have included two custom fonts and by referring this steps by stackoverflow questions....

[How to include and use new fonts in iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969329/how-to-include-and-use-new-fonts-in-iphone-sdk)

And Coded ....

```
 [lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"glyphish.ttf" size:[lbl minimumFontSize]]];
```

I am building this app for Base SDK 5.0

**The answer is,**

```
[lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"glyphish" size:[lbl minimumFontSize]]];
```

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have passed a filename (`glyphish.ttf`) instead of the actual font name. Most likely, the font name is `Glyphish`, but you need to query it somehow: either using the Mac's "Font Book.app" or via code: first, you need to query the family names via `[UIFont familyNames]`. Then, use `[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:]` to get the actual font names to load. For example, if your font contains a bold variant its family name would be `Glyphish` but font name would likely be `Glyphish-Bold`.

Answer (score 8):

First find that font in your available fonts list:

```
NSLog(@"fonts: %@", [UIFont familyNames]);
```

Then find and input the appropriate name.

Answer (score 3):

You should correct name. It should not contain ttf in glyphish.ttf. For exact reference refer following image for that. Dakota is font name in my case.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The font name is not the name of the file. Thus `glyphish.ttf` is not a valid font name.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use the font name, not the filename. you can check the name by opening the font file on yout mac.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the actual font name to be put in the app might be something else than `glyphish.ttf` .. i suggest opening font book and there checking the name of the font .and using that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the font name it may be different then the font file name...try this [link](http://www.amarendrasingh.in/objective-c/adding-custom-font-in-xcode/)

Go to your application build phases and add your font files in copy bundle resources

Answer (score 0):

Double click on the font file to open it in font book. Now see the name of the font on the top bar. Use this name in your code.