# Using custom font in XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uifont

I am having trouble adding this custom font:

```
[totalRecordedText setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"LiberationMono-Bold" size:19]];
```

I have added a file to my project called "LiberationMono-Bold.ttf". How do I now link the font file to the reference? Right now, it is not displaying the font (it just uses a system default).

Note that this **does** work by contrast:

```
[totalRecordedText setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ProximaNova-Bold" size:19]];
```

Comment: Does the not-working font has all characters you need to display?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom font is not working in my App?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534766/custom-font-is-not-working-in-my-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.ttf` file name may or may not be the same as the actual font name. This is what I do to find the real name of the `font` I want to use

```
for (NSString *font in [UIFont familyNames]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:font]);
    }
```

This will print out all the fonts that are supported by your system in a `dictionary` fashion, the Font-family name being the key. Find the key of your desired font and you will see all the sub-fonts in that key. Use that name in the command

`[totalRecordedText setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:<actual_font_name> size:19]];` and you should be good. !!

~ Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Use this example

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyFont" size:20];
[label setFont:font];
```

Where "MyFont" would be a TrueType or OpenType file in your project (sans the file extension), and label would be an instance of UILabel.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're saying. The format I'm using above works, as evidenced by the second font working, it's more a matter of the first font name or import or whatever the issue may be.