# Roboto font for ios

Tags: ios, fonts

I like the feel of roboto(Available for android Platform), and wish to use that for my app, I'm currently building. I have two question

1). How do I get Roboto in IOS? (Seems, I have no where to start with)
2). How do I set a particular font as the default font for my entire app?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Get the font [here](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/roboto).
Add the font to the app [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969329/how-to-include-and-use-new-fonts-in-iphone-sdk).
You can't set the font as default for the entire app, but the [appearance protocol](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiappearance) will help you.

Comment: the last link is broken

Comment: thanks @BetuUuUu sucks that apple have crazy links that change sometimes, updated

Comment: Setting font without overriding all of default sizes is here if anyone is looking.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51390172/3900139