# Using custom font for entire iOS app swift

Tags: ios, swift, fonts

I know that to set a custom font of an element on the screen I can simply do`someLabel.font=UIFont(name: "Exo 2.0", size: 15)`.

I was wondering how one could set it for an entire app using swift. (A hack would be to do what I know for every single element of the app but that is just going to be a maintainability nightmare)

I see that this question has already been asked with an objective-C tag, [How to set a custom font for entire iOS app without specifying size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907761/how-to-set-a-custom-font-for-entire-ios-app-without-specifying-size) but I'm not familiar enough with objective-C enough to port the code to swift

Comment: You could write a `UILabel` extension that returns the font you want in place of its internal font property.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can set the appearance of the UILabel and other UIViews:

```
UILabel.appearance().font = UIFont(name: "yourFont", size: yourSize)
```

More General:

```
AnyUIView.appearance().font = UIFont(name: "yourFont", size: yourSize)
```

Comment: my question is if i implement this,font size will also will over rided? how to avoid this ?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40484460/933770) works great for not overriding font sizes!

Comment: Is there a way to set the font globally like this without specifying the size? So that if I have a table cell with Subtitle style, the text will still show at the default size for those styles, in my chosen font?

Comment: @KrutarthPatel See my solution below. Font size is not overridden.

Answer (score 24):

As a more detailed answer and with these benefits I recommend using extensions:

- No size override (whatever you set in designer will be used)
- No style override (Bold, Light, Medium, UltraLight is implemented in my code but you can customize it as you need)

```swift
import UIKit

extension UILabel {
    @objc var substituteFontName : String {
        get {
            return self.font.fontName;
        }
        set {
            let fontNameToTest = self.font.fontName.lowercased();
            var fontName = newValue;
            if fontNameToTest.range(of: "bold") != nil {
                fontName += "-Bold";
            } else if fontNameToTest.range(of: "medium") != nil {
                fontName += "-Medium";
            } else if fontNameToTest.range(of: "light") != nil {
                fontName += "-Light";
            } else if fontNameToTest.range(of: "ultralight") != nil {
                fontName += "-UltraLight";
            }
            self.font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: self.font.pointSize)
        }
    }
}

extension UITextView {
    @objc var substituteFontName : String {
        get {
            return self.font?.fontName ?? "";
        }
        set {
            let fontNameToTest = self.font?.fontName.lowercased() ?? "";
            var fontName = newValue;
            if fontNameToTest.range(of: "bold") != nil {
                fontName += "-Bold";
            } else if fontNameToTest.range(of: "medium") != nil {
                fontName += "-Medium";
            } else if fontNameToTest.range(of: "light") != nil {
                fontName += "-Light";
            } else if fontNameToTest.range(of: "ultralight") != nil {
                fontName += "-UltraLight";
            }
            self.font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: self.font?.pointSize ?? 17)
        }
    }
}

extension UITextField {
    @objc var substituteFontName : String {
        get {
            return self.font?.fontName ?? "";
        }
        set {
            let fontNameToTest = self.font?.fontName.lowercased() ?? "";
            var fontName = newValue;
            if fontNameToTest.range(of: "bold") != nil {
                fontName += "-Bold";
            } else if fontNameToTest.range(of: "medium") != nil {
                fontName += "-Medium";
            } else if fontNameToTest.range(of: "light") != nil {
                fontName += "-Light";
            } else if fontNameToTest.range(of: "ultralight") != nil {
                fontName += "-UltraLight";
            }
            self.font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: self.font?.pointSize ?? 17)
        }
    }
}
```

**Samples for using Extensions:**

e.g. put these lines in your starting controller viewDidLoad

```swift
UILabel.appearance().substituteFontName = "IRANSans"; // USE YOUR FONT NAME INSTEAD
UITextView.appearance().substituteFontName = "IRANSans"; // USE YOUR FONT NAME INSTEAD
UITextField.appearance().substituteFontName = "IRANSans"; // USE YOUR FONT NAME INSTEAD
```

P.S. as @Christian mentioned, you can write your own extensions for almost AnyUIView

Comment: Is this still working for iOS 11 and swift 4? I got nil for the `self.font.fontName` in `UILabel`

Comment: I will check and let you know the result soon

Comment: Thanks, please leave comment when you could

Comment: Update: you have to add @objc to substituteFontName for keep the compatibility with swift4

Comment: Need to add @objc in order to work in swift project.

Comment: how to replace attributed text font globally using same concept ?

Comment: This overrides NSMutableAttributedString attributes when using a range for me.

Answer (score 5):

FINALLY figured this out. Cleanest way I could find. (Swift 4)
Solution doesn't require you to set font sizes and won't override all font sizes.

```
  UILabel.appearance().font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle(rawValue: "Roboto"))
```

For those looking for where to place this code. I put it in my AppDelegate.swift file inside of

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions...
```

**Swift 4.2**

```
 UILabel.appearance().font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle(rawValue: "Roboto"))
```

Comment: @DanielBeltrami You can put this right in your app delegate inside of....

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions 
And it should work application wide

Comment: Doesn't seems to work on iOS 12 with Swift 4.2, most of the texts' font size turn smaller then they should be.

Comment: At `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of course. But never mind, I found much better solution to change the font all over my app:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/40484460/8157190

Comment: doesn't work. overrides all font sizes on labels. in swift 5.

Comment: The answer clearly states swift 4.2. So doesn't work, isn't actually a correct response if you aren't talking about the same version @spnkr

Answer (score 2):

I found out a way to do same in **Swift 4 with iOS 11**

Only need to add `@objc` keyword before variable name.
So variable declaration will be like this

```
@objc public var substituteFontName : String {
    get {}
    set {}
}
```

Hope this helps others who are facing this issue.

Comment: I was facing this issue and wasted more than 2 days of my time to figure it out! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a combination of the answers offered already, but I had to try a combination of things to get it working in iOS 13:

This is all placed in a Table View Controller, which is made to conform to the UIFontPickerViewControllerDelegate in order to offer a view for the user to pick the font. 
This will update all the UILabels with the new font, but keep the other attributes.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    if cell === fontCell {
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            let configuration = UIFontPickerViewController.Configuration()
            configuration.includeFaces = true

            let fontVC = UIFontPickerViewController(configuration: configuration)
            fontVC.delegate = self

            present(fontVC, animated: true)
        } else {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "iOS 13 is required", message: "Custom fonts are only supported by devices running iOS 13 or above.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
            present(ac, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension AppearanceTableViewController: UIFontPickerViewControllerDelegate {
    func fontPickerViewControllerDidPickFont(_ viewController: UIFontPickerViewController) {
        // attempt to read the selected font descriptor, but exit quietly if that fails
        guard let descriptor = viewController.selectedFontDescriptor else { return }

        let font = UIFont(descriptor: descriptor, size: 20)
        UILabel.appearance().substituteFontName = font.fontName
    }
}

extension UILabel {
    @objc public var substituteFontName : String {
        get {
            return self.font.fontName;
        }
        set {
            let fontNameToTest = self.font.fontName.lowercased()
            var fontName = newValue
            if fontNameToTest.range(of: "bold") != nil {
                fontName += "-Bold"
            } else if fontNameToTest.range(of: "medium") != nil {
                fontName += "-Medium"
            } else if fontNameToTest.range(of: "light") != nil {
                fontName += "-Light"
            } else if fontNameToTest.range(of: "ultralight") != nil {
                fontName += "-UltraLight"
            }
            self.font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: self.font.pointSize)
        }
    }
}
```