# Setting app-wide default font that allows for varying sizes

Tags: ios, swift, fonts

I'd like to have all the text in my app show up in Oswald font. I've seen great answers that involve things like `UILabel.appearance().font = yourFont`. However, as far I can tell this requires constructing a font using `UIFont(name:_size:_)` which, of course, takes a size argument. This means that different labels that should be different sizes (like title and subtitle text in a Subtitle-style table cell) all show up at the same size.

Is there a simple way to set the font for the whole app once, and allow the sizes on different objects to be their standard size?

Supplemental questions:
1. What are the `UITextView`/`UITextField` equivalents of `UILabel.appearance().font`? `UITextView.appearance().font` doesn't appear to exist.
2. Is there a way in these app-wide statements to also effect things like Navigation Bar title fonts and Table Section Header fonts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using custom font for entire iOS app swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180449/using-custom-font-for-entire-ios-app-swift)

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707082/set-a-default-font-for-whole-ios-app

Answer (score 0):

I've found a very good though not completely comprehensive solution.

Most of my views are tables of one sort or another, so I've done the following
(note: I'm omitting the `FontNames` `struct` which includes a function to get bold/ital/light variations. also, big thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/44921262/6826164 for the subviews function.

```
extension UITableViewController {

open override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    for view in subviewsOf(view) {
        setFont(for: view)
    }
}

fileprivate func subviewsOf<T: UIView>(_ view: UIView) -> [T] {
    var subviews = [T]()

    for subview in view.subviews {
        subviews += subviewsOf(subview) as [T]

        if let subview = subview as? T {
            subviews.append(subview)
        }
    }
    return subviews
}

fileprivate func setFont(for view: UIView) {

    if let label = view as? UILabel {
        label.font = UIFont(name: FontNames.fontName(), size: label.font.pointSize)
    }
    else if let textField = view as? UITextField, let font = textField.font {
        textField.font = UIFont(name: FontNames.fontName(light: true), size: font.pointSize)
    }
    else if let textView = view as? UITextView, let font = textView.font {
        textView.font = UIFont(name: FontNames.fontName(light: true), size: font.pointSize)
    }
        // Technically this button font setting is unnecessary since the titleLabel will be covered as a UILabel in the view heirarchy,
        // but this allows a separate font for buttons if desired
    else if let button = view as? UIButton, let label = button.titleLabel {
        button.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: FontNames.fontName(), size: label.font.pointSize)
    }

}

}
```

There's a number of things this doesn't cover, of course, including:

1. Navcon titles
2. Tab bar titles
3. Section index titles
4. Alert controllers/action sheets
5. Any other VCs that aren't Tables, obviously.

Any thoughts/tips on being more comprehensive, including other specific views I'm likely to encounter that aren't accounted for here (not counting the catchall #5 of course)? I've tried solutions mentioned in the comments and haven't quite been able to make any of them work as well as this one.

Also, any thoughts on a better place to put this besides `viewDidLayoutSubviews` since that one gets called at random? I've tried putting it in `viewWillAppear` but that doesn't work for some reason.