# How can I use a custom font through an entire app in Swift 4 / Xcode 10.1?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have tried some answers on here to set a custom font for a whole app, but none seem to be working in Xcode 10.1. I was wondering if anyone has some advice?

Here is what I have tried so far;
[Using custom font for entire iOS app swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180449/using-custom-font-for-entire-ios-app-swift)

[Set a default font for whole iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707082/set-a-default-font-for-whole-ios-app/40484460#40484460)

Here is a code sample: (This is still giving me system font)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UILabel.appearance().font = UIFont(name: "Times New Roman", size: 17)

    let label1 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100))
    label1.text = "Hello"
    view.addSubview(label1)
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: you have to add that first code into AppDelegate.the swift file inside of ``func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions...```

Comment: And if you are using latest swift so use this line 
 UILabel.appearance().font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle(rawValue: "Times New Roman"))

Comment: And much better solution is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707082/set-a-default-font-for-whole-ios-app/40484460#40484460

Comment: @brontea cross check font type face name, correct one you need to  give here UIFont(name: "Times New Roman", size: 17).I hope you have added font in plist.

Comment: @iOSTeam yeah i tried putting that line in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions func, but still no result. I'll try the answer you suggested

Comment: @Sakshi i did double check, thanks for the thought

Comment: @iOSTeam that answer was really helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you may do using an extension of UIFont

```
extension UIFont {

   public enum FontWeight {
      //cases are just font family like bold, light, italic
      case .light
   }


   func appFont(weight : FontWeight, size : CGFloat) -> UIFont {
      var fontName = "Times New Roman-"
      switch weight {
         case .light {
             fontName = fontName + "light" // add your family name here
         }
      }
      return UIFont(name: fontName, size: size)!
    }
}
```

in case of a label

```
label.font = UIFont.appFont(weight : .light, size : 17)
```

Comment: is there a way to set this for all the uilabels? Thanks

Comment: @brontea you can subclass UILabel and set font in that, Make labels in your app from that subclass.

Comment: that's a good idea, thanks!