# Use custom-font in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I would like to use custom font in my app, but I keep getting error

```
[RCTLog][tid:0x78f70450][RCTConvert.m:581]>Unrecognized font family 'Roboto'
```

Does this mean I have to mess with the iOS's way to import font directly?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That's because iOS does not have the Roboto font available by default.

Exactly. To make it available you have to include it in your project from Xcode. Just follow the [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625605/roboto-font-for-ios) that this answer provides, it's pretty straightforward.

Once you have done this, then you should have no problem using it from JS.

Comment: just run `react-native link` in you console in project folder. Works for Android & iOS

Comment: @aakash-sidgel's answer is much easier

Answer (score 39):

1. Create a new group Fonts within your Xcode project
2. Drag and drop fonts from Finder to the Fonts group you just created, and check your project name in Add to targets list
3. Expand your project name folder within the main directory in your project and open Info.plist
4. Add `Fonts provided by application` as a new key
5. Add a new item under `Fonts provided by application`, and set the item value to the full font name with extension for each font you've added to the fonts folder

   - i.e. if the font file name is `OpenSans-ExtraBold.ttf`, then that should be the value of the item.
6. To use the font in React Native, simply set the `fontFamily` style attribute for the element (see [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html)).  Note that the style should use the *name* of the font rather than the file name.

   - e.g. in the example above, the style attribute would be `fontFamily: 'Open Sans'`
7. Run Shift + Command + K to clean last build
8. Then Command + B to start a new build
9. And finally Command + R to run the application

If you still see the error Unrecognized font family restart your react packager.

https://github.com/alucic/react-native-cheat-sheet

Hope it helps!

Comment: OH the step 10. restart react packager did the work. Thanks :)

Comment: Needed to add it to "Copy Bundle Resources" as well.

Comment: I forgot to append '.ttf' the suffix... THX!

Comment: this also works: `right click Fonts and select "Add files to <project name>"` then select font files on finder

Comment: All answers are somewhat related to prepackaging the font in the project, anyone who has done dynamic downloading of the font in runtime and saving it and then using it. Typically Chinese fonts are huge and increase the app size drastically.

Answer (score 32):

## UPDATE

You don't need to install rnpm manually now. After step one, in step two, you can just use the command `react-native link` and all your assets will be linked. rnpm is now being merged with react-naitve. Checkout this commit on RN https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/e8b508144fdcdea436cf4d80d99daec757505c70

---

There is an easier way of doing things through `rnpm. It adds fonts to both android and ios. Place the font you want to add to a suitable location inside your project directory. In your package.json just add the following:

### step1

```
...
    "rnpm": {
          "assets": ["path/to/your/font/directory"]
    },
...
```

### step2

Then from command line do: `rnpm link`

you can now happily use your fonts in your app.

Note: you have to have rnpm installed for this to work. 
Just do `npm install -g rnpm`

Here is the documentation: https://github.com/rnpm/rnpm#advanced-usage

Comment: now that rnpm is merged into react-native, I should be abe to do it from react-native directly, correct?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but it should be possible. I will update the answer once I've tested it. @AndréJunges

Comment: It didn't work for me for IOS - I had to follow the steps from @alucic`s answer

Comment: I just tried it out, it works for me. Did you rebuild the project after running react-native link? You will still need to add the `rnpm` entry to the package.json through. @AndréJunges

Comment: hmm, Rereading now I may have missed one step. I pointed the font path to the original directory, outside the project.. like `/Library/Fonts/..`

Comment: Thanks @AakashSigdel.  Worked and much easier than the other solutions.

Comment: One detail missing here is that the "fontFamily" in react native should be the name of the font, not the name of the font file (on Mac you can open up the font in Font Book to see the font name, which appears in the title bar)

Answer (score 23):

The answer from Aakash is correct.

**Method:**

1. Add your font to a folder in your react-native project
2. Add to package.json the following

> ```
>  "rnpm": {
>     "assets": ["./your/fonts/folder"]
>   }
> ```

3. run `react-native link` in your terminal

Optionally:

1. add rnpm using `npm install -g rnpm`
2. run `rnpm link`

**Example usage**

1. I put myFont.ttf in a folder whose path (relative to package.json) is
   ./src/assets/fonts
2. I put the following code in package.json file

> ```
>   "rnpm": {
>     "assets": ["./src/assets/fonts"]
>   }
> ```

3. I run in terminal

> react-native link

4. I use it in a Text element in react-native like this:
   (without the space after the first < and without the space before the last > )

> < Text style={{ fontFamily: myFont }}> Hello MyFont! < /Text >

**Images:**
[package.json link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwJVD.png)

Thanks for the great answer Aakash, hope you don't mind the re-breakdown for noobs like myself out there!

Comment: When I run `react-native link` then font I added in my assets/fonts is being removed automatically, how to solve this because the font still not working

Comment: hi I'm not sure what is happening.. where are you placing the fonts exactly? (ie i use atom editor and put the folder in there). A snapshot of the issue may be useful?

Comment: It is working now, I just added it under **/android/app/src/main/assets/fonts/** and then avoid using `fontWeight: 'bold'` on the style because it breaks the custom fonts making it not to work. Re-build the app and done. :)

Comment: should i import the font?

Comment: should i import the font?

Answer (score 5):

Many answers are here for **react-native version < 0.60**

For those who are using **react-native version > 0.60** , **`'rnpm' is deprecated`** and custom fonts will not work.

Now, in order to add custom font in react-native version > 0.60 you will have to :

1- Create a file named `react-native.config.js` in the root folder of your project.

2- add this in that new file

```
module.exports = {
  assets: ['./assets/fonts/']
};
```

3- run `react-native link` command in the root project path.

**PS** Make sure you have the right path for the fonts folder before running `react-native link` command

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Create React Native App, when running `react-native link` you will see this:

> `react-native link` can not be used in Create React Native App
>   projects. If you need to include a library that relies on custom
>   native code, you might have to eject first. See
>   https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md
>   for more information.

If all you are trying to do is to add custom fonts, instead of ejecting, you could use Expo, which is also included by default with CRNA. Essentially, you do:

```
await Font.loadAsync({
  'open-sans-bold': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf'),
});
```

Also, you can only do `ttf` or `otf` formatted fonts, no `ttc` fonts: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app

Here is a detailed doc from Expo: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-custom-fonts

Answer (score 0):

1. add the font files (i.e. **.otf** OR **.ttf**) in root/assets/font folder in your project.
2. in **package.json**:
   rnpm: "assets": ["./assets/font"],

   3. if after building your fonts are not being supported then add this one file in root level:

**react-native.config.js**

```
 module.exports = {
    project: {
        ios: {},
        android: {},
    },
    assets: ['./assets/fonts']
    };
```

4. **ex:** font-name -> **Robotto-Regular.ttf** 
   then use it like below in styles:

> ```
> fontFamily: 'Robotto-Regular'
> ```

5. run **react-native link**
6. Then in android side(android studio) and ios side(Xcode) sync the project.
7. run **react-native run-android** OR **react-native run-ios**

This should resolve any errors which will be coming of fonts not supporting and you can use your custom fonts.

Answer (score 0):

create a file i.e defaultconfig.js

and in this file  add the fonts then use

in widget by `fontfamily:''montoface`