# Google fonts in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, fonts, webfonts

I was wondering if it'd be possible to use Google fonts in my React Native project.

I've been looking for some information but I didn't find anything.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

P.D.: I know I can download it and include it into my project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use custom-font in React-Native](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310828/use-custom-font-in-react-native) - you're going to have to download the webfonts, and bundle them, as long as that doesn't violate their font license.

Comment: I know I can download the fonts and add them to my project.

What I'd like to know if it's possible to include it directly from Google Fonts.

Thanks.

Comment: @JVLobo did you ever figure out how to do this? or did you end up downloading the font assets?

Comment: I guess I just downloaded... this was 4 years ago and I haven't worked anymore with that. sorry

Answer (score 27):

If your React Native project was bootstrapped with the [Expo CLI](https://expo.io/), you can now incorporate Google Fonts into the project using the [`expo-google-fonts`](https://github.com/expo/google-fonts) package.

Install the packages:

```
expo install @expo-google-fonts/dev expo-font
```

**Note**: `dev` will allow you to import any font style from any of the [Expo Google Fonts packages](https://directory.now.sh/). This will load fonts over the network at runtime instead of adding the asset as a file to the project (good if you don't know what font to use):

```
import {
  useFonts,
  Roboto_400Regular,
  Bangers_400Regular,
  OpenSans_400Regular
} from "@expo-google-fonts/dev";
```

If on the other hand you already know what font you're going to use, run:

```
expo install @expo-google-fonts/FONT_FAMILY_NAME expo-font
```

For example, if you choose to use `Roboto` we would install:

```
expo install @expo-google-fonts/roboto expo-font
```

To avoid rendering text before the font is loaded, install the `expo-app-loading` package to use the `<AppLoading />` component:

```
expo install expo-app-loading
```

Then in your project file use the font like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { AppLoading } from "expo-app-loading";
import {
  useFonts,
  Roboto_400Regular,
  Roboto_400Regular_Italic
} from "@expo-google-fonts/roboto";

export default function App() {
  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    Roboto_400Regular,
    Roboto_400Regular_Italic
  });

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  } else {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Text style={{ fontFamily: "Roboto_400Regular", fontSize: 28 }}>
          Nice! Support for Google Fonts!
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: my code won't go to the `else` block,  what does useFonts do?

Comment: getting this error ``@expo-google-fonts/dev` from file `F:\coding\android\newcontacts\my-app\components\Carditem.jsx`, the package `F:\coding\android\newcontacts\my-app\node_modules\@expo-google-fonts\dev\package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`F:\coding\android\newcontacts\my-app\node_modules\@expo-google-fonts\dev\index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:      
`

Comment: import AppLoading from "expo-app-loading";

Answer (score 7):

Download google fonts from here : [Github Google Fonts](https://github.com/google/fonts/)

Suppose your font is Quicksand, you can do something like this in index.ios.js :

```
import _ from 'lodash';

var OldText = Text;

class NewText extends OldText {
  defaultProps = {
    customFont: false
  }

  render() {
    var props = _.clone(this.props);

    if (this.props.customFont) {
      return super.render();
    }

    if (_.isArray(this.props.style)){
      props.style.push({fontFamily: 'Quicksand-Regular', fontSize: 12});
    } else if (props.style) {
      props.style = [props.style, {fontFamily: 'Quicksand-Regular', fontSize: 12}];
    } else {
      props.style = {fontFamily: 'Quicksand-Regular', fontSize: 12};
    }

    this.props = props;

    return super.render();
  }
}

Object.defineProperty(React, 'Text', {value: NewText});
```

Then add you font in xCode in  => Build Phases => Copy Bundle Resources

Then check you have the following in your projects Info.plist :

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>Quicksand-Bold.otf</string>
    <string>Quicksand-BoldItalic.otf</string>
    <string>Quicksand-Italic.otf</string>
    <string>Quicksand-Light.otf</string>
    <string>Quicksand-LightItalic.otf</string>
    <string>Quicksand-Regular.otf</string>
    <string>Quicksand_Dash.otf</string>
</array>
```

This did the trick for me.

Comment: I don't get it.

How do you import the font from Google Fonts??

Thanks.

Comment: You can download the TTF files from their Github: https://github.com/google/fonts

Answer (score 1):

```
// expo will figure out which version of expo-font will work with the current version of expo that installed
expo install expo-font
```

get the custom font that you want to install [expo google fonts](https://directory.vercel.app/)

```
 expo install @expo-google-fonts/oswald
 expo install @expo-google-fonts/delius-unicase
```

You might have been using multiple fonts

```
import AppLoading from "expo-app-loading";
import {
  useFonts as useOswald,
  Oswald_400Regular,
} from "@expo-google-fonts/oswald";

import {
    useFonts as useDelius,
    DeliusUnicase_400Regular,
    DeliusUnicase_700Bold
} from "@expo-google-fonts/delius-unicase";

const [oswaldLoaded] = useOswald({
    Oswald_400Regular,
  });

const [deliusLoaded] = useDelius({
    DeliusUnicase_400Regular,,
  });



if (!oswaldLoaded || !deliusLoaded) {
    return AppLoading;
  }
```