# React Native San Francisco Fonts, Medium and Light

Tags: ios, react-native, fonts

I'm trying to use different SF fonts in an app I'm styling. The original design uses a variation of fonts like...

`SF Compact Display-Black
SF Compact Display-Bold
SF Compact Display-Heavy
SF Compact Display-Regular
SF Compact Display-Semibold
SF Compact Text-Medium
SF Compact Text-Semibold
SF UI Text-Regular`

But my iOS simulator doesn't recognize any of these.

Since SF is the default font, should I be instead using `fontWeight` to make the font bold, heavy, regular, etc?

Comment: Does it work as expected on a physical device? Are you able to test that? Perhaps its just the simulator, not something you're doing.

Comment: Please give some more information on how did you add all the variants of the fonts and how are you trying to use them in code.

Comment: The fonts listed is how I would try to use them. Also tried `San Francisco` and `SFCompactDisplay-Heavy`

Comment: Can you try with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310828/use-custom-font-in-react-native)?