# How to set the custom font family globally at once and use throughout the react-native app without calling in every 'Text' component?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

As per this [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310828/use-custom-font-in-react-native) solution custom font can be used by calling it in each and every `Text` component. But we may happen to miss the same font family when we have some thousands of `Text` components in our App. Then we lose consistency in case of font family.

Hence, Is there any way to use custom font family by not calling in every `Text` component?

Comment: Are you looking to use the same font as a common global variable?

Comment: Check this answer :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/60428079/2853407

Answer (score 1):

**You can override Text behaviour by adding this in any of your component using Text:**

*Edit: Add this code in your App.js or main file*

```
let oldRender = Text.render;
Text.render = function (...args) {
    let origin = oldRender.call(this, ...args);
    return React.cloneElement(origin, {
        style: [{color: 'red', fontFamily: 'Arial'}, origin.props.style]
    });
}
```

*For react Native Version 0.56  or below, Add this code in your App.js or main file*

```
let oldRender = Text.prototype.render;
Text.prototype.render = function (...args) {
    let origin = oldRender.call(this, ...args);
    return React.cloneElement(origin, {
        style: [{color: 'red', fontFamily: 'Arial'}, origin.props.style]
    });
};
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35255645/how-to-set-default-font-family-in-react-native)
Or [create your own component, such as MyAppText.](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text) 
*MyAppText would be a simple component that renders a Text component using your universal style and can pass through other props, etc.*

Answer (score 0):

Just go through the below link, I believe this your requirement

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#limited-style-inheritance

[How to set default font family in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35255645/how-to-set-default-font-family-in-react-native)

Comment: In this solution constants are being used instead of hard coded values. But i am looking for a way not to use neither hard coded values nor constants. As I stated in the question font family should be changed throughout the app automatically.