# How to implement a font family in React Native 0.60+

Tags: android, ios, react-native, fonts

#### Problem

I have been searching the internet for a guide to using a custom font family in React Native (0.60+, no Expo). Currently all guides and answers seem outdated, incorrect, or incomplete. Specifically how do you implement a whole range of font weights and styles into a custom font (correctly using the `fontWeight` and `fontStyle` properties)?

#### Background

I expect that there is a solution which properly utilizes the `fontWeight` and `fontStyle` style props alongside `fontFamily`. However the solutions I've found do not do that. Some of them:

1. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=22LEiBYBiTw) solution shows multiple font types. However it changes between bold and regular via the `fontFamily` style prop (changing the family between `"Montserrat-Regular"` & `"Montserrat-Bold"`)
2. This [guide](https://github.com/refinery29/react-native-cheat-sheet) and [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30540901/5277913) both outline only referencing the font family's base name when using it (e.g. `fontFamily: "Montserrat"`) and then choosing the desired weight and style via `fontWeight` and `fontStyle`. Testing with several fonts from google fonts (both as a .ttc and .ttf) does not yield results (at least not in Android). Both solutions are from years ago using `rnpm` which leads me to believe they are outdated.

So far I have not found an up to date solution which works as expected. Perhaps it's not possible but that does not make sense given the font system which is in place.

#### What I expect to happen

Given the style props:

```
 {
    fontStyle: "italic",
    fontWeight: "400",
    fontFamily: "Montserrat"
  }
```

I would get text in the Montserrat font, italicized, with weight 400. No attempts that I have tried so far do this. How can I?

#### What I have tried so far:

- Using a react-native.config.js like this:

  ```
    project: {
        ios: {},
        android: {},
    },
    assets: ['./assets/fonts']
  }
  ```

  and `react-native link`, I've imported font files both as a set of .ttf and a merged .ttc, no luck there. With the .ttf, I had to change the fontFamily name to the file name, couldn't use weight and style. The .ttc didnt seem to work at all.
- (Android specific) I've attempted to make a `montserrat.xml` file in `android/app/src/main/res/font` as per [the spec on the Android Developers website](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/font-resource), did not seem to produce anything.

---

I'm hitting a dead end with this. I dont quite understand why there is the bother with `fontWeight` and `fontStyle` style props if they cant even be used outside of the default fonts. Any help with this is appreciated, thanks.