# Font size issue in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, fonts

I am trying to set the font of the `label` as per follow but it gives me zero `CGSize` for that.

```
UIFont *abbrFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Cyrillic Bold_5" size:50]; //Helvetica Cyrillic Bold_5 added Custom Font

CGSize abbrSizeOfString = [_addbrTitle sizeWithFont:abbrFont];//_addbrTitle is a NSString
NSLog(@"%f %f",abbrSizeOfString.width,abbrSizeOfString.height); //Everytime Prints (0.000,0.000)
```

Help me to solve this.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that abbrFont is not nil?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376941/how-to-use-custom-fonts-in-iphone-sdk
check this

Comment: i'm pretty sure your font name is not correct. So please review it.

Comment: I think this is your answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969329/how-to-include-and-use-new-fonts-in-iphone-sdk

Comment: i'm pretty sure your font name is not correct and if _addbrTitle is a label you should change _addbrTitle.text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
UIFont *abbrFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:50]; //Helvetica Cyrillic Bold_5 added Custom Font
CGSize abbrSizeOfString = [_addbrTitle.text sizeWithFont:abbrFont];//_addbrTitle is a Label
NSLog(@"%f %f",abbrSizeOfString.width,abbrSizeOfString.height); //E
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line to set the size for label..

```
[label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UILabel *_addbrTitle = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[_addbrTitle setText:@"Hello"];
UIFont *abbrFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:50]; //Helvetica Cyrillic Bold_5 added Custom Font
[_addbrTitle setFont:abbrFont];
CGSize abbrSizeOfString = [_addbrTitle.text sizeWithFont:abbrFont];//_addbrTitle is a Label
NSLog(@"%f %f",abbrSizeOfString.width,abbrSizeOfString.height); //Everytime Prints (0.000,0.000)
```

Font name you have entered in the code does not exists in system. So its printing (0,0) every time. Enter a font name which exists in system it will print the size.

Answer (score 0):

change your font name to some other built in font name  then try
like this

```
yourLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your font name is not current follow this IOS supporting fonts list and Font name

http://iosfonts.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *fontURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"your_font_name"  ofType:@"TTF"]];
```

**for example:**

```
NSURL *fontURL2 = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"segoe_semi_bold" ofType:@"TTF"]];

 NSURL *fontURL2 = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"segoe_semi_bold" ofType:@"TTF"]];
```

**now make add url to array**

```
NSArray *arrFont =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:fontURL1,fontURL2, nil];


int result =CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURLs((CFArrayRef)arrFont, kCTFontManagerScopeUser, nil);
if(result)
{
  NSLog("Font Install successfully");
}
```

now you can get font