# can't set custom font to uibutton programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, uibutton

I'm trying to use ubuntu font for uibutton programmatically (button is also created programmatically and it's custom). Here's what I've done.

```
[self.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Ubuntu" size:20.0]];
```

but no luck. I've checked everything.
- font is included in build phases
- I've added font in info.plist

But when I add label from interface builder and set ubuntu font from attribute inspector then everything works fine. Font is applied also on uibutton. but when I remove that label problem persists.
What's going on here?

Edit:
I've already followed steps provided in answers of similar problems. like this.
[How to include and use new fonts in iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969329/how-to-include-and-use-new-fonts-in-iphone-sdk)

Comment: yourButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Ubundu" size:20.0];

Comment: @Spynet Apparently there isn't any problem with code. Like If I use  [self.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:20.0]]; Then It works just fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include and use new fonts in iPhone SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969329/how-to-include-and-use-new-fonts-in-iphone-sdk)

Comment: So your custom font adding process is wrong , the above link sounds good

Comment: Already answered many times over stackoverflow. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969329/how-to-include-and-use-new-fonts-in-iphone-sdk

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376941/how-to-use-custom-fonts-in-iphone-sdk/14377069#14377069

Comment: @iAhmed I've already done those steps. That's what I'm telling it that font is included in info.plist file. then also it is not working.

Answer (score -1):

Just make sure all the fonts really are available in the bundle, try printing all fonts and check if you are using the correct name. You can very easily do this with following code in app delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
for (NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames]) {
NSLog(@"Family Name : %@", familyName);
for (NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]) {
    NSLog(@"\tFont Name : %@", fontName);
 }
}
```

**In Alphabetic Order:**

```
for (NSString* family in [[UIFont familyNames] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)])
{
  NSLog(@"%@", family);

for (NSString* name in [[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:family] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)])
{
    NSLog(@"  %@", name);
 }
}
```

Get of your font from printed values and then use it as you are already doing.
Hope it helps

Comment: No it's not. Only when I add label from interface builder and set its font to ubuntu then it's name is printed.

Comment: It means your fonts are not being added in your project resources. OR not added correctly in plist.