# How do I set bold font on UILabel in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, uilabel

I want to set bold font on `UILabel`. I generate label by coding. when i try to set bold font on label ios set system regular font but i want to set 'Noto sans-Bold' font. In storyboard set font completely.

My code is

```
UILabel *lblName=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 25, 100, 21)];
lblName.text=@"Hello World";
[lblName setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Noto Sans-Bold" size:15.0]];
[self.view addSubview:lblName];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lblname.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Noto Sans-Bold" size:18];`

and one more thing check your font correctly it is available in list or not.

Here is a list of available fonts .

[List of available fonts](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/6000-list-uifonts-available.html)

**EDIT:-**
or if you want to set font which not available in xcode then you have to first install it in XCode 
please follow this tutorial.

> [Install custom fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969329/how-to-include-and-use-new-fonts-in-iphone-sdk)

As said by [Jilouc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/555004/jilouc)   follow this procedure.

> 1. Add the font files to your resource files
> 2. Edit your `Info.plist`: Add a new entry with the key `Fonts provided by application`.
> 3. For each of your files, add the file name to this array
>
> On the example below, I've added the font "DejaVu Sans Mono":
>
> [image]   In your application you can
>   the use `[UIFont fontWithName:@"DejaVuSansMono-Bold" size:14.f]`.
>
> Or if you want to use it in html/css, just use `font-family:DejaVu
>   Sans Mono;`

Comment: 'Noto sans' font not display in this list but i add this font in project directory.

Comment: @iOSGuru Your font won't show in that list because its not a native font. Check my answer for code that will list all the fonts available to you including custom ones you have installed. If its not in the list, you have installed it incorrectly, and in that case, follow the installation advice above.

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't got the formatting of your font title correct, it will automatically default back to system font.

The issue is with your font name and since Noto isn't native it's going to be difficult to know exactly what name you need to provide.

Make sure you have added that font to your project.

You can check your available fonts by running this code:

**SWIFT**

```
for familyName in UIFont.familyNames() {
    print("\n-- \(familyName) \n")
    for fontName in UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(familyName) {
        print(fontName)
    }
}
```

**OBJECTIVE-C**

```
for (NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames]){
    NSLog(@"Family name: %@", familyName);
    for (NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]) {
        NSLog(@"--Font name: %@", fontName);
    }
}
```