# Set custom font name and size for button in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How to Set custom font name and size for button in iOS 9 Objective-c?

Thank You.

Comment: http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

Comment: possible duplicate  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969329/how-to-include-and-use-new-fonts-in-iphone-sdk,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
[objBtn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@“fontname” size:fontsize]];
```