# Not able to print custom label name in console until i use it in NIB?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilabel

I added some custom fonts in xcode and in my font book i want to set the font name programatically in my code but i can not able to access there name until each one is used in my NIB file.

Comment: LABEL.font = UIFont(name: "FONTNAME", size: 17)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969329/how-to-include-and-use-new-fonts-in-iphone-sdk