# Error - Use of undeclared identifier [UIFont familyNames]

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uikit, uifont

I am getting a strange error use of undeclared identifier for the method `[UIFont familyNames]`

I have included three frameworks to the project as below.
1. Foundation framework
2. UIKit framework
3. Coregraphics framework.

Here is the screenshot of the error for reference
[image]

Can any one explain why i am getting this and how to fix this?

Comment: put your font in your project and add this font in your .plist file

Comment: This method is not using any custom fonts whatsoever. This is a basic method that get the list of font family names already existing in the system @HimanshuMoradiya

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969329/how-to-include-and-use-new-fonts-in-iphone-sdk refer this link your issue will be solve

Comment: add #import <UIKit/UIKit.h> in .h file

Comment: Thanks @ChandreshKachariya. Silly me. That solves the issue. Could have   marked as an answer if it was in answers rather than comments