# Font type of items in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

How can you change the font type of the items in `UITableView`? I have been trying to do it for quite sometime but i am not able to get it to change. I am new at programming so kindly explain in the simplest way possible.
This is the entire Code

```
**ViewController 1**
import UIKit
import Foundation

var items:[String] = []
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{


    var cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]
    return cell

}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if var storeditems: AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("items") {
        items = []
        for var i = 0; i<storeditems?.count; ++i {
            items.append(storeditems?[i] as NSString)
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

            if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
                items.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(items, forKey: "items")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
**View Controller 2**

import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {

    items.append(textField.text)

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(items, forKey: "items")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

Comment: you want to change font of cell.titleLabel ?

Comment: I want to change the font of the text that is saved to every row in the table. If that means the same thing

Comment: As i said i am extremely new to programming.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the Font type and size in UITableView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281768/is-it-possible-to-change-the-font-type-and-size-in-uitableview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below code for the set tableview cell **Font** as well as **background color**.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [yourAry objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row)];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir Next" size:16]; // set font style
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:239.0/255.0 green:239.0/255.0 blue:239.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]; // set tableview cell background color.
    return cell;
}
```

In swift Language

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
        var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel.text = String(yourAry[indexPath.row] as NSString)
        cell.textLabel.font = UIFont (name: "Avenir Next", size: 16) // set font style

        return cell
```

Comment: So i used it, however, it returns an error that says UITableView, numberofrowsinsection: Int -> Int does not have a member named dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Comment: Can you provide me some code for the numberofrowsinsection and cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: Please check items.count > 0 or not in numberofrowsinsection method. or when your items array is refreshing.

Comment: items.count != 0 but, it is in the numberOfRowsInSection method if i remove items.count from that method, it won't be possible for row to update each item an item is typed into the textField and added to the table